# Store/Google Analytics transactions discrepancy

Tags: expresso-store, analytics, google

Is there any reason why Store might not be logging transactions with Google Analytics apart from JS being disabled/unavailable? We have some orders not showing up in GA and the client is keen on identifying the underlying cause.

Comment: What version of EE and Store are you using?

Comment: EE is 2.5.1 and Store is 1.6.3

Comment: Which payment gateway are you using? Are all the orders not in GA using the same payment gateway?

Answer (score 2):

Store relies on the customer landing on the payment complete/invoice page for the Google Analytics e-commerce tracking to work.

Depending on which gateway you are using (especially if it is an off-site gateway), some customers might simply close their browser after they see the gateway's "payment complete" page, and not click through to your final invoice URL. If that is the case, there is no way for the orders to be reported to GA.

Comment: Many thanks Adrian - that makes a lot of sense as we're using WorldPay to handle transactions off-site